# Firebase Facebook Authentication Error with openFB in Ionic

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, openfb

I can successfully access the facebook userdata via the OpenFB API, but when I try to use:

```
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
auth.$authWithOAuthToken("facebook", accessToken)
```

to authenticate the user through Firebase, I get the following error:

[Firebase Auth Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBjWK.jpg)

I've tried adding several OAuth redirect URIs in the Facebook developer console:

[Facebook O AUth Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOPf2.jpg)

I'm using the correct App ID and App Secrect from Facebook.  Any ideas?

Comment: why are  you not using the authPopups? Where are you getting the accessToken you are using - https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html

Comment: I'm using the AngularFire $firebaseAuth service.  I was using openFB.login() to get an accessToken, and now I'm using this plugin to get an accessToken via the native Facebook app:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Both approaches are successfully retrieving data from Facebook, but both also fail when trying to authenticate with Firebase.

Since Firebase recently underwent some major changes, could this have broken the functionality of the AngularFire auth services?